# How to make square canvas centered on the screen?

Tags: html, css, canvas, center

I have a canvas in my game. I want it to be positioned on the center of the screen.
For example, something with width and height, to cover the screen, not overflow, and **it has to be a square**.

How can I do that only with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use CSS `@media` and `aspect-ratio`.

```css
#canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
  #canvas {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```